# JayDeBeApi Crashing on Connection

Tags: java, python, database, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to connect to a GoodData warehouse through Python using the JayDeBeApi modules but for whatever reason whenever I make the connection the console immediately crashes.

I've been able to successfully connect using the SQL client DBVisualizer with the jar file they have me but it doesn't appear to be working for Python.

code:

```
import jaydebeapi

connection = jaydebeapi.connect('com.gooddata.dss.jdbc.driver.DssDriver', 
                            ['jdbc:dss://na1.secure.gooddata.com/gdc/dss/instances/INSTANCE_ID','user','password'], 
                            'JAR_FILE')
```

Anyone have any insight into why this may be crashing? I'm not able to get any error logging returned. If there is another module you can use to connect to JDBC DB that'd also be helpful.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: If *that* is exactly what you have, then replace `JAR_FILE` with the actual path to the .jar file. See doc at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/JayDeBeApi/#usage

Comment: the jar_file is actually replaced with the path in the code, just pulled that out here. From what I can tell it also might be an issue with Jpype itself working with Windows 7 but I still can't diagnose.

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem - did you ever get to the bottom of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem, seems like the issue was the version of JPype I was using was not compatible with the GoodData Driver. I installed JPype 0.6.0 and that solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was crashing on connection because I had a 32-bit version of Python installed but a 64-bit version of Java. This is listed as a cause of crashes in [JPype's documentation](http://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

`Mixing 64 bit Python with 32 bit Java and vice versa crashes on import jpype.`

After installing 64-bit Python and using that instead, I was able to connect without any problems.